# Concrete 5.8.2 Class 'finfo' not found

Tags: php, concrete5, concrete5-8.x

I have searched the web and I have searched my server I am unable to find the php.ini for my site. I am getting the following error for my site.

> Class 'finfo' not found
>   Details
>   G:\inetpub\wwwroot\landoll.com\concrete\vendor\league\flysystem\src\Adapter\Local>.php(311): Whoops\Exception\ErrorException->null

```
   public function getMimetype($path)
{
    $location = $this->applyPathPrefix($path);
    $finfo = new Finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); /*This is Line 311*/
    $mimetype = $finfo->file($location);

    if (in_array($mimetype, ['application/octet-stream', 'inode/x-empty'])) {
        $mimetype = Util\MimeType::detectByFilename($location);
    }

    return ['path' => $path, 'type' => 'file', 'mimetype' => $mimetype];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`finfo` is a PHP extension.
http://php.net/manual/en/class.finfo.php

Depending on your web hosting, there may be an area in the hosting control panel to enable it. If not, you may need to contact your hosting technical support and ask them to enable it for you.

Comment: Thank you, I had to go into my on-site server and change the PHP configuration settings to add the line extension=php_fileinfo.dll under  Dynamic Extensions section of the php configuration.